# Kubernetes: how to write cluster token to a file?

Tags: kubernetes, token, kubeadm

I use the following command to create cluster token :

```
kubeadm token create --ttl=0
```

This will show the following output:

> W0504 18:31:48.031557   20703 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm
> cannot validate component configs for API groups
> [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]

Now after using `kubeadm token list` commnad, I want to copy the token to a file.

How to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the `token list` can be formatted with jsonpath:

```
kubeadm token list -o=jsonpath='{.token}{"\n"}' > tokens.txt
```

By using this format only the token is printed by the list command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is the token suppose to be this short ?! when I do `kubeadm token list` I see a short line and that is why I was looking to copy the long-version of he token in a file ..

Comment: according to the doc a token has the following format: "[a-z0-9]{6}.[a-z0-9]{16}"
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-token/#synopsis